# Python (preferably 3) equivalent to INKEY$

Tags: python, keyboard, buffer, basic

I am using Python 3.6.4 on a Windows 7 system (I have other systems like Win 10 and Android but this is my starting point).

INKEY$, for those not familiar with BASIC (pretty much any flavor), is a function that checks the keyboard buffer, returning that data as a string or a null/empty value ("") if there was no data, and clears the buffer. The length of the returned string depends on the data in the buffer, normally 0, 1, or 2 on a single keystroke (a fast typist could fill the small buffer between checks in the old days). The Enter key was not needed (unless that was what you were looking for) or processed and the program did not pause unless programmed to do so.

Pauser:

```
    a$=""
    while a$=""
    a$=inkey$
    wend
```

Flow Interrupter:

```
    a=0
    while a < 1000
        a=a+1
        print a
        a$=inkey$
        if a$<>"" then exit while
    wend
```

Quick parser:

```
    a$=inkey$
    if a$<>"" then
        rem process input
        rem like arrow keys/a w s z for directional movement
        rem useful for games and custom editors
    end if
```

I am wanting to know if Python has a simple cross platform function (ie not 10+ lines of code unless in an importable module/class) that is the equivalent to the INKEY$ function?  Also, I am not wanting to import the gaming module(s), just want an INKEY$ function equivalent (simple, straight forth, small).

```py
    import inkey
    a = inkey.inkey()
```

Update #1:
After I installed the readchar module and corrected a reported error by Python (stdout.write(a) needs to be stdout.write(str(a)) as the variable 'a' appears to be returned as a byte string from readchar() function) when using the code listed by Mr. Stratton below, I only get continuous stream of b'\xff' and console echoed characters if there where any keypresses.

Stripping it down to use only the function doesn't help either:

```py
    from readchar import readchar
    from sys import stdout
    import os

    #I like clear screens, and I can not lie
    os.system('cls')  # For Windows
    #os.system('clear')  # For Linux/OS X

    def inkey():
        "INKEY$ function"
        return readchar()
        #let the processing hit the floor, elsewhere

    b=0
    step = 1
    while b < 1000:
        b = b + step
        print(b)
        #convert bytes to integers
        a = int.from_bytes(inkey(), "big")
        #remember I keep getting b'\xff' (255) when buffer is empty
        if chr(a) == "a":
            step = step - 1
            a = 255 #don't stop
        if chr(a) == "l":
            step = step + 1
            a = 255 #don't stop
        if a != 255:
            break
```

It is supposed to count b from 0 to 999, stopping on almost any keypress, 'a' decreases the step, 'l' increases it.  Instead, it prints the keypress either before or after the value of b depending on timing and continues until b = 1000. Nothing I did made a difference.

While the Pauser function can be replaced with an input() (i = input("Press Enter key to continue")) the other two variants can't be changed so easily it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to what you’re looking for is probably the [readchar](https://pypi.org/project/readchar/) library.

Here’s an example that resembles the old BASIC logic:

```
from readchar import readchar
from sys import stdout

a = ' '
while ord(a) not in [3,24,27]:
    a = readchar()
    stdout.write(a)
    stdout.flush()
    if ord(a) == 13:
        stdout.write("\n")
```

Those numbers that break the loop are CTRL-C, CTRL-X, and ESC respectively. The number 13 is the carriage return; the example writes a line feed following each carriage return to avoid overwriting text.

The equivalant to the old `ASC(A$)` in BASIC is `ord(a)` in Python. (And `CHR$(A$)` is `chr(a)`.)

Note that this will block on reading. If no keypress is waiting, Python will stop on the line `a = readchar()` until a key is pressed. To get the full effect of BASIC’s `INKEY$`, you’ll need to verify that some data is waiting before reading it. You can do this using Python’s [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) library.

```
from readchar import readchar
from sys import stdin, stdout
from select import select

def inkey():
    if select([stdin,],[],[],0.0)[0]:
        return readchar()
    return ''

a = ''
timer = 0
while a != 'Q':
    a = inkey()
    if a != '':
        stdout.write(a)
        stdout.flush()
        if ord(a) == 13:
            stdout.write("\n")
    timer += 1
    if timer > 1000000:
        print("Type faster, human!")
        timer = 0
```

This defines an `inkey` function and returns the empty string if nothing is waiting. If something is reading, it returns `readchar()`. Every 1,000,000 times through the loop, it tells the human on the other end to type faster.

In this version, it quits on a capital letter “Q”, as this does not block CTRL-C, CTRL-X, and ESC from breaking out of the program altogether.

This may have trouble if you’re using Windows, as `select.select` at least at one time did not work on Windows. I have no means of testing that, however.

You may also want to look at [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) if you don’t need it to look exactly like BASIC. The canonical means to do this in Python is probably to set up an event that calls a function or method. Your script goes on doing its thing, and if that function (or method) is invoked, it cancels or modifies the action of the main loop.